# OAuthCard not returning token after signin activity

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm creating a Teams bot. I have added signin activity to my Teams bot.

When I'm trying to signin, it gives me a popup to signin and after completing signin the token is not returned. So "WaitForToken" is never called.

I was able to sign in using same bot last week. Can anyone help me to understand about any recent changes in OAuthCard for bots?

The signin code is as follows:

```
private async Task SendOAuthCardAsync(IDialogContext context, Activity activity)
        {
            var reply = await context.Activity.CreateOAuthReplyAsync(ApplicationSettings.ConnectionName,
                "Please sign in to continue.", "Sign In", true).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await context.PostAsync(reply);

            context.Wait(WaitForToken);
        }

 private async Task WaitForToken(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;

            var tokenResponse = activity.ReadTokenResponseContent();
            var channelData = context.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>();
            if (tokenResponse != null)
            {
                // Use the token to do exciting things!
                await context.PostAsync($"Your sign in is successful");
            }
            else
            {
                string input = activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message ? Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams.ActivityExtensions.GetTextWithoutMentions(activity)
                                                                : ((dynamic)(activity.Value)).state.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                {
                    tokenResponse = await context.GetUserTokenAsync(ApplicationSettings.ConnectionName, input.Trim());
                    if (tokenResponse != null)
                    {
                        // Use the token to do exciting things!

                        await context.PostAsync($"Your sign in is successful");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                await context.PostAsync($"Hmm. Something went wrong.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1553).

Were you using the middleware in order to get it to work initially? The middleware would look something like:

```cs
// hook up onSend pipeline
turnContext.OnSendActivities(async (ctx, activities, nextSend) =>
{
    foreach (var activity in activities)
    {
        if (activity.ChannelId != "msteams") continue;
        if (activity.Attachments == null) continue;
        if (!activity.Attachments.Any()) continue;
        if (activity.Attachments[0].ContentType != "application/vnd.microsoft.card.signin") continue;
        if (!(activity.Attachments[0].Content is SigninCard card)) continue;
        if (!(card.Buttons is CardAction[] buttons)) continue;
        if (!buttons.Any()) continue;

        // Modify button type to openUrl as signIn is not working in teams
        buttons[0].Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl;
    }

    // run full pipeline
    return await nextSend().ConfigureAwait(false);
});
```

There was an update recently that made it so you no longer need the middleware. Instead, follow these steps:

1. Remove the middleware from your bot (if you have it)
2. Create your Teams Bot in the App Studio Manifest Editor
3. Under Domains and Permissions, ensure that `token.botframework.com` has been added as a valid domain.

   - Optionally, enable Web app Single Sign-On with your appId and `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect`
4. Click Install and start talking to your bot

Alternatively, I believe you can just update all of your packages to 4.4 and add this to the top of your `OnTurnAsync()`:

```cs
if (turnContext?.Activity?.Type == ActivityTypes.Invoke && turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == "msteams")
    await Dialog.Run(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
else
    await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
```

If that doesn't work, you can try using this:

```cs
protected override async Task OnUnrecognizedActivityTypeAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext?.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Invoke)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
        new Activity()
        {
            Type = ActivityTypesEx.InvokeResponse,
            Value = null
        });
        await Dialog.Run(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The middleware made it so the cards in Teams use `Action.OpenUrl` (which no longer works) instead of `Action.Signin` (which is what every other channel uses).